# How to deploy to multiple hosts with azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps provides YAML pipelines which can apparently only be run in Agent Pools (not Deployment Pools). However, when a job is run, *it is only run on one host* (agent) in that pool. Since there seems to be no way to create a non-YAML pipeline - how does one deploy to multiple hosts? The scenario here is on-prem agents running on windows servers.

Comment: AFAIK it is still possible to create non-YAML pipelines? For a release, they are available in the menu under Releases. For builds, you choose the classic editor (last of all options) when creating a new pipeline

Comment: @HenryBeen You are correct. Both types of pipelines are still supported.

Comment: When I go this route I still have to choose an Agent Pool and don't get to choose a Deployment Pool. This again means my pipeline runs on only one agent/host and I want to run it on many. Where are deployment pools used anyway??

Comment: @Marc Deployment pools can be used from a Release, by adding a deployment group job to a release stage. See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#types-of-jobs and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-group-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: The following discussion of the Azure Pipelines muddle is very helpful: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **BUILD** pipeline w/o using YAML:

[image]

Create a **RELEASE** pipeline:

[image]

With a **Deployment Group Job**:

[image]

However none of this helps you if you haven't added your target machines to the **[Deployment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops)**

[image]

YAML definitions are not yet supported for release pipelines. Multi-stage **build** pipelines allow the release of code if you're using containers and cloud native apps running on **[Environment Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#resources)** like AKS (kubernetes).

Comment: Will this (non-YAML release pipelines) work if we're using on-prem agents?

Comment: If you have your agents in a **deployment group**, then you can assign release pipeline jobs to run on those agents by their group name (and tags).